# One-way Upgrade from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2015 (SSIS and SSAS projects)

Tags: ssis, migration, ssas, project

I was given a code set that was developed in Visual Studio 2005 and it needs to be migrated to Visual Studio 2015.

About the code set: It is a mix of SSIS and SSAS projects.
About the machine:
Visual Studio 2015
MSSQL Server 2016 with SSIS, SSRS and SSAS installed

When Visual Studio 2015 attempt to upgrade the code, it crashes midway and restarted. There was no error prompt. From the Event Viewer I got this

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIShell.GetDialogOwnerHwnd(IntPtr ByRef)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.Service.DataWarehouseEnvironmentService.get_TopmostWindow()
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.ErrorReportingService.ShowNetServersErrorMessage(ErrorInfo)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.ErrorReportingService.ShowErrorMessage(ErrorInfo)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.ErrorReportingService.ShowPendingErrors()
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.Project.FileProjectHierarchy.InitializeSourceControl()
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.Project.FileProjectHierarchy.Load(System.String, UInt32, Int32)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.Service.DataWarehouseProjectManagerService.CreateProject(System.String, Int32, Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Designer.Serialization.DocumentObject, Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.Project.IFileProjectManager, System.Guid)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.Service.DataWarehouseProjectManagerService.CreateProject(System.String, System.Guid)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.PVsProjectFactory.CreateProject(System.String, System.String, System.String, UInt32, System.Guid ByRef, IntPtr ByRef, Int32 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIDataSource.Invoke(System.String, System.Object, System.Object ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DataSource.Invoke(System.String, System.Object, System.Object ByRef)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsCommand.Execute(System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(System.Windows.Input.ICommandSource, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

I am suspecting it to be an incompatible dll, but I am not sure. There is an existing dll in ..\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.DLL

Only certain SSIS/SSAS project crashes the IDE.

Is there a way that I circumvent this? Or did I missed a step on the method to the migration of SSIS/SSAS projects?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok. I found a way that seem to work. I excluded the problematic SSIS/SSAS project from the migration. Then using SSDT, upgrade those projects separately. Then reload the projects in the main solution.